# kendo pivot grid rowheadertemplate

Tags: templates, kendo-ui, grid, pivot

I have a kendo pivot grid defined in this way:

```
<div kendo-pivot-grid
     id="pivotGrid"
     k-excel="{ fileName: reportCtrl.CurrentReport.DS_REPORT + '.xlsx' }"
     k-height="'100%'"
     k-sortable="true"
     k-filterable="true"
     k-row-header-template="'#= rowTemplate #'"
     kx-data="resultCtrl.ReportResult"
     kx-data-source-options="{
        data: resultCtrl.ReportResult,
        schema: {
            fields: {
                DT_MEASURE: { type: 'shortDate' }
            },
            cube: {
                dimensions: {
                    ID_MEASURE_A: { caption: 'Measure A' },
                    ID_MEASURE_B: { caption: 'Measure B' },
                },
                measures: {
                    'AverageA': { field: 'ID_MEASURE_A', aggregate: 'average' },
                    'AverageB': { field: 'ID_MEASURE_B', aggregate: 'average' }
                }
            },


        },
        columns: [
           { name: 'ID_PRODUCT', expand: true }
        ],
        rows: [
           { name: 'DT_MEASURE', expand: true },
        ],
        measures: ['AverageA', 'AverageB']
     }"
     kx-vertical-stretch="true">
</div>
```

And here the script `rowTemplate`:

```
<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  # if (member.name.indexOf("DT_MEASURE") === 0 && member.name !== "DT_MEASURE") { #
      #: kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(member.caption), "dd-MM-yyyy") #
  # } else { #
      #: member.caption.toString() #
  # } #
</script>
```

I want to define my rowHeaderTemplate to show the correct format of a date but every attempt to do it doesn't work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you share a runnable demo? Probably you can setup something in http://dojo.telerik.com ?

Comment: i try but can't cause i haven't ds please complete it http://dojo.telerik.com/@saber13812002/EbOPAV